# rails - form to disply non-input type fields in nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I guess this is a newbie question, but what is the syntax in a form to show contents of fields not as a text box/area, but rather like label would appear.

```
<% form_for @user do |f| %>
    <% f.fields_for :user_ingreds do |builder| %>
        <p>
            <%= builder.??? %>
        </p>
    <% end %>
<% end%>
```

user `has_many :user_ingreds` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_ingreds`.

Basically I want to make a list of `user_ingreds` where the user can't edit the data but can remove the record from the list via a button.

However the fields_for builder doesn't recognize a direct call to to the fields in `UserIngred` model (ie, `builder.user_id` throws and error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a non-editable list of the ingreds with a button to remove them, then don't make a form.

Instead, display your data and a button beside them created with link_to and pointing to your delete function.

If ever you want to really display the content of your form variable, you can access it this way:

```
builder.object.user_i
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. 

I'd like the user be able to delete from the list, and then save or cancel at the end. So I thought I needed a form with a _destroy hidden field.

You are suggesting a separate function, however if the user won't commit until the end how would you keep a reference of what records will be deleted? Thanks!

Comment: ok, so have a look here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1